# jquery mobile multipage wont work

Tags: jquery-mobile, multipage

Please help,

jquery mobile multipage wont work when a page is called from another page. It only displays the buttons but doesnt navigate to its internal pages when clicked. It works fine when the page is access directly.

```
<!-- Page 1-->
<div data-role="page" id="description" data-title="Description">
<div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-theme="d">
<!-- header 1-->`enter code here`
</div>  
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<!--- content 1-->
</div>
<div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed" data-theme="d">
<div data-role="navbar"  data-iconpos="bottom">
<ul>
<li><a href="#description" data-role="button" data-icon="star">Description</a></li>
<li><a href="#physicians" data-role="button" data-icon="star">Physicians</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Page 2-->
<div id="Physicians" data-role="page" data-title="Physicians">
<div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-theme="d">
<!-- header 2 -->
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<!-- content 2 -->
</div>
<div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed" data-theme="d">
<div data-role="navbar"  data-iconpos="bottom">
<ul>
<li><a href="#description" data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-transition="pop">Description</a></li>
<li><a href="#physicians" data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-transition="pop">Physicians</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding to the anchor the attribute `rel="external"`.

**Example:**

```
<a href="#description" data-role="button" data-icon="star" rel="external">Description</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try giving `<div data-role="page"` first for your second page

Comment: oh, it has <div data-role="page" , missed to paste it in my question

Comment: give that attrib before mentioning `id="physicians"` in your second page & try it

Comment: the same effect :(. actually i swapped the positions of data-role and id tag before to try if it will solve the issue.

Comment: I doubt if you can have any other attrib for `<div data-role="page">` please remove the other attribs. Here is some helpful [link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html)

Comment: data-title and id attribs are used for multipage

Answer (score 0):

When you call this page from another page, it **ONLY** loads the div[data-role="page"] of that page, not the other div in this multi-page file!

Actually to be precise, when you link to a page from another page, ONLY the code inside the div you are targeting is pulled in via AJAX, even if you had JS in the `<head>` that won't get loaded either.

Try linking to this page with an external link and you'll find it works fine.

Comment: No, The page is not loaded from another page. what i mean the page is clicked from another page. And i don't have other js file aside from the jquery mobile.

Comment: example i have a multipage : multipage.html

The multipage functionality works fine when you browse the file directly. But if

you have a page like: home.html and it has a link to multipage.html the multipage functionality of multipage.html doesnt work. If you refresh the page, it will work again.

Comment: Try data-ajax="false" on your a href= to your page   <a href="index.html#phyiscian" data-ajax="false">My Link</a>